# Running two instances of Android emulator, second instance is slow

Tags: android, performance, android-emulator, haxm

When I run two separate Android Virtual Devices using two instances of the Android emulator, the second device launched is extremely slow and laggy (the first device is fine). This slowness continues even after I kill the first device.

I also noticed the second device eats a huge amount of host CPU (around 230%) whereas the first device only uses around 30%.

My host runs Mac OS X 10.11.6 and has a quad-core i7 processor.

What could cause this issue?

Comment: There's a known bug that when OS X goes on sleep and back to active emulators start eating all the CPU. Does this happen if you close all emulators and reopen them? Also are they for x86 and what API # are they running?

Answer (score 1):

Open your AVD's settings and hit `Show Advanced Settings`. Under `Emulated Performance` you can choose to use your GPU to render faster. You can also adjust RAM for the virtual devices under `Memory and Storage` in the same menu. Hope this works.